# jQuery - e.preventDefault conundrum / can't submit form after preventing default

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit, preventdefault

Goal:  Stop 'submit' button, validate field, create popover alerting of results, submit form when popover is closed.

So I have a hidden popover div, and when the submit button is pressed I do this to check for certain conditions AND display the popover:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
      if (($("#conditions").find("input:checkbox:checked").length ) || $('#radio_condition_1').is(":checked")) {
        $("#popback").css('display', 'block');
    }
 });
```

Then I THOUGHT this code would submit the form once the popover is cleared:

```
$("#popback").click(function() {
    $("#popback").css('display', 'none');
    $("form").submit();

});
```

without:

```
$("form").submit();
```

The second code works fine to clear the popover.  However, with the submit function inserted it not only doesn't clear the popover, it also doesn't submit the form.

NOTE:  there are two forms on the page.

Help?

Comment: Have your tried `e.stopPropagation()`?

Comment: @ForeignObject will that prevent form submission..?

Comment: Do you have multiple forms? can we have a minimal demo such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @Tilwin Joy.. It shouldn't, but it may stop the first `event` from being prevented. @NotaGuruAtAll remove `e.preventDefault()` from `submit()` and see if they both fire properly.

Comment: I've setup a basic fiddle, seems to work:  http://jsfiddle.net/6F2zU/6/

Comment: @NotaGuruAtAll see my answer and concept verification below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
$('form')[0].submit();
```

What you have `$('form').submit()` triggers the submit event thereby firing the submit handler again which in turn prevents default form submission and you're back where you started!

[**CONCEPT VERIFICATION**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/t8X6P/)

**Step 1:** Load the demo above and you'll see `submit event triggered` in the console.

**Step 2:** Now uncomment `$('form')[0].submit()` and comment out `$('form').submit()` and click `run` and viola .. the form is submitted .. by-passing the `submit` event handler.

**CONCLUSION:** ... see above.

**UPDATE**

If you have more than one form on the page the code above can be adjusted to target the relevant form. For instance, to submit the first form on the page:

```
$('form').first()[0].submit();
```

Or simply use any selectors, such as ID or css, that provides the need level of specificity.

Comment: That simply triggers the `submit` event which is already prevented, whereas `[0].submit()` submits the form - default action.

Comment: Please note that that post does not use `event.preventDefault()` as the OP is.

Comment: Interesting, if i use the native submit first and then switch back to jquery one, then it works, otherwise no joy http://jsfiddle.net/kS3ms/1/

Comment: You've got to see my demo before you draw any conclusions. The demo shows you what I have been saying all along and leaves no doubt. This is a fact that amazed me too when I first came across it :)